# How can I teach Eclipse with AngularJS Plugin to resolve directives and CSS classes in templates

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, eclipse

I installed Nodeclipse (which includes the AngularJS Eclipse Plugin) and configured a project to be an AngularJS project, which works fine. In my main HTML file the angular directives and CSS classes are resolved correctly.

But in Angular templates, the validator seems not to be able to resolve anything. I guess it is because no CSS file is linked in the template's HTML (it is only linked in the main HTML file).

Is it possible to teach Eclipse to validate the template files correctly?
If so, how can I achieve this?

Regards
Markus

Comment: This feature is not supported, please create an issue at https://github.com/angelozerr/eclipse-wtp-webresources/issues

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I created issue https://github.com/angelozerr/eclipse-wtp-webresources/issues/52 for that.

Answer (score 0):

There is a useful workaround for this that works with the web-resources plugin in eclipse Neon (1.1.0). In the project settings, under "Web resources -> CSS", there is the option to search CSS class and id in all the project's CSS files, if there is no link.

[image]

This assumes that your template file has access to every css file in your project, so it is still error prone. However, if you don't keep around orphaned css files, it works very well.